# Получение контента сайта https://www.transfermarkt.us/ (парсинг)

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Уважаемые коллеги. Мне нужно распарсить на php сайт https://www.transfermarkt.us/ и его внутренние страницы. Пытаюсь это сделать двумя способами:
1.

```
$url="www.transfermarkt.us";
$h=fle_get_content($url);
```

2.

```
$url="www.transfermarkt.us";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$header=array(":authority" => $url,
"method" => "GET",
":method" => "GET",
":path" => "/",
":scheme" => "https",
"accept" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language" => "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,da;q=0.6,pt;q=0.5,hmn;q=0.4,bg;q=0.3",
"cache-control" => "max-age=0",
"cookie" => "TMSESSID=p1agl77bld5hn3c0bsalapmkf6; _ga=GA1.2.1046738243.1587399746; OB-USER-TOKEN=bafe9ddd-194f-409a-982f-faf11dad10db; __gads=ID=974a44ebcf9d6077:T=1587399749:S=ALNI_MbT1rczgOOMGWQNmf7UZZ-Y0cTMnw; oil_data={%22opt_in%22:true%2C%22version%22:%221.3.2-RELEASE%22%2C%22localeVariantName%22:%22enEN_01%22%2C%22localeVariantVersion%22:1%2C%22customPurposes%22:[]%2C%22consentString%22:%22%22%2C%22configVersion%22:1}; _gid=GA1.2.1714158336.1587676360; POPUPCHECK=1587888244665; _gat=1; ioam2018=0015b21390be3648e5e9dc373:1616170946833:1587399746833:.transfermarkt.us:98:transfer:home_rest:noevent:1587815232473:ajsvrl",
"referer" => "https://".$url,
"sec-fetch-dest" => "document",
"sec-fetch-mode" => "navigate",
"sec-fetch-site" => "same-orign",
"sec-fetch-user" => "?1",
"upgrade-insecure-requests" => "1",
"user-agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36");
$h = curl_exec($ch);
```

В обоих случаях получаю ошибку Failed to connect to www.transfermarkt.us: Connection timed out, хотя в браузера страница открывается без проблем. Не подскажете ли решение?

Comment: протокол в ссылке мб указать?

Comment: Все-равно не помогает

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); - уберите, если тело нужно, а оно вам нужно.

file_get_contents

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогает. У меня складывается впечатление, что https://www.transfermarkt.us/ ввел какую-то антиспам фишку